# Second 'exception when others' fails

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

I am trying to use EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS to catch non-existent tables that I try to DROP, as follows:

```
begin
execute immediate 'drop table X';
exception when others then null;
end;
```

If table x exists and I run this, the table is dropped and all is well.  If I run it again, there is no table to be dropped, but the EXCEPTION thing results in the script proceeding happily.  So far, so good.

The problem appears if I try to do this more than once.

If I run this script to drop tables X and Y:

```
begin
execute immediate 'drop table X';
exception when others then null;

execute immediate 'drop table Y';
exception when others then null;
end;
```

I get the following error information:

Error starting at line : 1 in command -

```
begin
execute immediate 'drop table X';
exception when others then null;

execute immediate 'drop table Y';
exception when others then null;
end;
```

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:

( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
   pragma raise return select update when while with
    
    << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge
ORA-06550: line 7, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
   member constructor map
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

What am I missing here?  If I removed the second EXCEPTION WHEN statement, the script fails if table Y doesn't exist...  I need to catch this error...

Comment: Don't use "when others then null" because there are other exceptions that could occur. Instead, catch the exception you are expecting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801453/103295

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer here:

[Two PLSQL statements with begin and end, run fine separately but not together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024418/two-plsql-statements-with-begin-and-end-run-fine-separately-but-not-together)

Apparently I need

```
begin
    begin
        some stuff
    end;
    begin
        some other stuff
    end;
end;
```

or to put a / after each of the two inner block END; 's...

Answer (score 0):

`exception when others then null;` applies to a single Begin/End block.  It's not really valid to have multiples in a single block.  You can get around this by having multiple blocks that are individually caught.

```
begin
execute immediate 'drop table X';
exception when others then null;
end;
/

begin
execute immediate 'drop table Y';
exception when others then null;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I tried it... and I tried with a ; after the first END, also.  No joy...


Error starting at line : 1 in command -
    begin
    execute immediate 'drop table X';
    exception when others then null;
    end;
    begin
    execute immediate 'drop table Y';
    exception when others then null;
    end;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action: